# Continous Integration of an Angular2/Typescript project

Tags: angular, jenkins, continuous-integration, bitbucket

So I'm on this Angular2 project, generated with angular-cli. So it has webpack2 behind it and also Typescript.

I use **ng serve** for serving my project, **ng build** to generate the *dist* folder and solution and life's great.

Now I have to integrate all this into **Jenkins** for the Continous Integration process. Must say also the project is hosted on **BitBucket**.

Anyone has an example for this particular configuration.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This is a really open question.

I have experience with this. I would advise use of the Jenkins pipeline plugin. This supports multi-branch pipelines which are so cool (select this when first creating a job).

Basically, they watch all branches on one of your repos and a Jenkins job is auto-created for each branch.

Now you can tell if a branch is passing or failing the build before merging to master.

You create a Jenkins file that describes the build pipeline. This is stored in the repo.